# How to set directory in antcallbacktask?

Tags: java, ant

In ant task in ant, we have a property named 'Dir' where i can specify the base directory to be used in the called target. I am looking for something similar in 'ant callback' task. How can i set the directory in ant callback

Comment: Let know the specific thing you want to achieve along with the code that you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

`<antcall>` and `<antcallback>` are tasks which can be used to call other targets within the same file. `<antcallback>` has all attributes of `<antcall>` except that `antcallback` allows the properties of the called target to be accessed back in calling target. For more details, refer [AntCall](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html) and [AntCallback](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/antcallback%5ftask.html)

However, `<ant>` task is generally used to call a target in another Ant file. Hence, the `dir` attribute comes into significance.